# Is it possible to add function definitions programmatically in swift

Tags: swift

I'm creating a struct that holds 3 float values,

```
struct Col {
  var r: Float
  var g: Float
  var b: Float
}
```

and I'd like to add a bunch of function definitions that are equivalent to the built in math functions, but that operate piecewise on the members of my struct

I can do it by hand, eg

```
func pow(a: Col, b: Col) -> Col {
  return Col(r: pow(a.r, b.r), g: pow(a.g, b.g), b: pow(a.b, b.b))
}
```

but this is tedious and error prone.

What I'd like to do is create a function to turn the original math function into my Col version, so that I could call it like this:

```
defineColVersion(pow, noArgs: 2)
```

and it defines the new version, without overwriting the built in function that operates on Doubles

Is there any way to do this in Swift?

Thanks

Comment: Instance methods or type methods should be adequate for your problem, if I understood it correctly.

Comment: You could not do this with generics, nor generics are way to do solve things like this.

Swift is a type-safe language, if this was Javascript it could be solved in a second, however Swift typechecks when you want to get reference of any member of a struct/class in compilation time, and you may easily understand that type T (which is actually placeholder) has (should have) no member `r`, `g` or `b`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually think this is exactly what you want:

```
func toCol(f: (Float, Float) -> Float) -> (Col, Col) -> Col {
    return { a, b in
        Col(r: f(a.r, b.r), g: f(a.g, b.g), b: f(a.b, b.b))
    }
}

func toCol(f: Float -> Float) -> Col -> Col {
    return { c in
        Col(r: f(c.r), g: f(c.g), b: f(c.b))
    }
}

let pow = toCol(Darwin.pow)
let sin = toCol(Darwin.sin)
let log = toCol(Darwin.log)

let a = Col(r: 0.4, g: 0.2, b: 0.7)
let b = Col(r: 0.3, g: 0.9, b: 0.3)

pow(a, b)
sin(a)
log(b)
```

The two overloaded functions `toCol` take a unary/binary function on `Float`s and returns a new function which does the same on your `Col` type. With those two, you can easily create a `pow` function for your `Col` type.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I want.

I didn't even try it because I assumed the 
let pow = toCol(Darwin.pow)
would overwrite the version that takes Doubles, but it actually overloads it :)

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to programmatically define new functions in a static language like Swift. What you can do, however, is to make a higher-kinded function:

```
func init(a: Col, b: Col, function: (Float, Float) -> Float) -> Col {
    return self.init(r: function(a.r, b.r), g: function(a.g, b.g), b: function(a.b, b.b))
}

Col(Col(1, 2, 3), Col(3, 4, 5)) { $0 * $1 }
Col(Col(1, 2, 3), Col(3, 4, 5)) { pow($0, $1) }
```

Comment: This is what I'm going to do, just a little correction for Swift struct initializer syntax:

`init(_ a: Col, _ b: Col, _ function: (Float, Float) -> Float) {`

   `self.init(r: function(a.r, b.r), g: function(a.g, b.g), b: function(a.b, b.b))`

 `}`

Answer (score 0):

```
func init(first: Col, second: Col, function: (Float, Float) -> Float ) {
    newR = function(first.r,second.r)
    newG = function(first.g,second.g)
    newB = function(first.b,second.b)
    return self.init(r:newR,g:newG,b:newB)
}
```

I'm not in a position to compile this so it probably has some errors but hopefully it will be useful. You would use it like so:

```
first = Col(r:1,g:2,b:3)
second = Col(r:1,g:2,b:3)
combined = Col(first:first,second:second) { pow($0,$1) }
```